# html form table td value is not saving in database of django

Tags: python-3.x, django, post, html-table

I am trying to save td value which I am getting through Js in database using django.
I am specifying name to td but its not saving giving me this error. :**(1048, "Column 'total' cannot be null")**
td is in my footer(tfoot)

Why my value is not saving in database on POST :

html

```
<tfoot>
        <tr>
           <th colspan="5"></th>
           <th    id="total">Total :</th>
           <td name="total" id="total_value"></td>
         </tr>
</foot>
```

views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        total=  request.POST.get('total')
    or 
            total=  request.POST['total']
```

Comment: could you spec\unclear to me : a) where's the POST request coming from b) what your view is doing

Answer (score 0):

That is because "POST" data comes from the following tags/elements :

1. `<button></button>`
2. `<input></input>`
3. the above elements being inside a `<form></form>` block where the form `method="POST"`

**For example:**

```
<html>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="td-name" placeholder="name of td"></input>
        <button type="submit" name="td" value="5">OK</button>
    </form>
</html>
```

I am not sure there is a way to send "POST" data from tables. If you want to see what data is available in "POST", put the following after the "if" statement:

```
print(request.POST)
```

That will show you a dictionary containing values in POST.  Do you see any values or keys for "td" there?  I think not.  If you want that data in POST, you need elements that return those values. "td" does not.

What exactly are you trying to do?